# Memurai hangs while processing

Tags: windows, redis, memurai

I am using Memurai 2.0.2 for cache in my distributed application. It runs different services on different machines and all services have Memurai details with them.
The problem that happens is, that sometimes Memurai process just hangs. The Memurai process keeps on running but no queries are served. I am not able to create a connection to it. It's log file consists of an error:

```
Error trying to rename the existing AOF to old tempfile: Broken pipe
```

This generally occurs when I restart the Memurai service. Although I am not sure what is the reason for it. Memurai works fine if I restart its service once.

What can be the issue here? What steps can I take to avoid/ minimize its occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

Memurai 2.0.2 is fairly outdated now. Perhaps get the latest version (3.1.4 at the time of this response) at https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai

Answer (score 0):

For whoever looking for an answer, this happened because another service restarted Memurai service when background rewriting of AOF was in progress. Due to this, some zombie processes were getting created and when Memurai started again, this error was coming up.

The solution that we did was to check if any background rewriting is happening by using settings `aof_rewrite_scheduled` and `aof_rewrite_in_progress` from `Persistence` info. If any of these flags is true then don't stop the service.